# Babel Error: Unknown Option: babelrc.presets

Tags: npm, webpack, babeljs

When running tests using Jest, I need my .babelrc file for it to run.
When running npm start, it only works without the .babelrc file, with the error:

```
Unknown option: C:\...\babelrc.presets
```

I'm guessing it's to do with the version of babel I have, but I have tried to following "answer" to this question: [Unknown option: .../.babelrc.presets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685365/unknown-option-babelrc-presets)
but to no avail.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "author": "x",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "react-addons-test-utils",
      "fbjs"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.*",
    "babel-jest": "^11.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "jest-cli": "^11.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.8",
    "webpack": "^1.12.*",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.3"
  }
}
```

and my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
     "react",
     "es2015"
  ]
}
```

and my webpack config, if it's relevant:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You've listed `babel-core@^6` but are using `babel-loader@5`, update your `babel-loader` to the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I can work with `babel src --out-dir lib`, but not with `npm run XXX` using babel-core@6.20.0 and babel-loader@6.2.9 .While I install Babel-cli@6.18.0 CLI globally on my machine, after I install babel-cli@ locally project, it can works with `npm run`.